# pyTelegramBotApi и register_next_step_handler

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Всем привет, не могу решить проблему связанную с register_next_step_handler'ом в Телеграм апи.
Проблема состоит в том, что register_next_step_handler не запускается есть бота добавить в группу, однако если писать самому боту, то он нормально реагирует на этот кусок кода.

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(apiToken)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def testCommand(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="ТЕСТОВОЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ ПО ФУНКЦИИ /START")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["test_ticket"])
def testTakeInput(message):
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Опишите вашу проблему")
    print(sent)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, nextStep) '# Не выполняется, если добавить бота в группу. Выполняется лишь при повторном вызове (/test_ticket)'

def nextStep(message):
    print(message.text) 
    bot.reply_to(message, text="Спасибо за обращение, проблема в обработке")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def testReply(message):
    if message.text == "test":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="ТЕСТОВОЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ")

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Хм, а какую реакцию от этого кода вы ожидаете? У вас же запрограммировано - если ввести `test_ticket` то и вызовется метод `next_step_handler`

Comment: Если обращаться к боту непосредственно через группу самого бота, то после /test_ticket он ждет пока я ему что-то напишу, после написанного текста он выдает "Спасибо за обращение"
Однако если обращаться к нему через иную группу, куда вы его добавите, то он уже пропускает момент с задержкой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно выставить было админ права боту в группе, даже если они были выданы ранее в канале куда вы его добавляли

Answer (score 0):

Используй aiogram

1 Он асинхронный

2 Нормальные **"этапы"** (просто укажи в хендлере state)

3 Есть шорткаты `message.answer('Ответ')`

4 Похожая структура (замени bot на dispecher)

5 Есть документация

6 Есть русское сообество t.me/aiogram_ru

7 Не завершается после каждой ошибки (их можно регистрировать @dp.error_handler())

8 Типизация (Редактор кода будет подсказывать функции)

Это мое мнение по поводу aiogram и я никого не хотел обидеть или что-то подобное это просто моя рекомендация.